# Python: Creating a streamplot with limited data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been puzzled about this issue for some time now, regarding the creation of streamplot given what I would consider limited data compared to the examples I've seen.

I am attempting to plot streamlines of particles in a flow field given the following information on each particle: x coordinate, y coordinate, x-component velocity, y-component velocity. Each of these data sets is in the form of a one-dimensional array. Based on the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=streamplot#matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot) of the streamplot function in matplotlib, the first two input arguments should be one-dimensional arrays, and the third and fourth should be two-dimensional.

So, my question is: what is the most accurate way to create a streamplot based on the data I have? I have tried using the [`griddata`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata) function in scipy to create grids out of the velocity data, but I'm not quite sure how to decide on appropriate `xi` values (or from doc: "Points at which to interpolate data") when using this function.

Please excuse the generality of this question, as it might be more about the theory behind a streamplot than python syntax itself.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use griddata to make an evenly spaced pattern from your given points. Use it separately on x-velocities and y-velocities. `xi` values are merely points at which you want to create approximations, just play with the values to see which will give you visually attractive result, it merely defines the fineness of your mesh.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Could you give me an example of how I can create an array of `xi` values?

Comment: Use numpy linspace `x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)`